# Google Places API - How to return nearest locations?

Tags: objective-c, google-places-api

My application uses Google Places API Nearby search to grab the locations nearest to the user. I specify all the possible types found on "https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types".

My search query looks a little something like this: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=myKeyHere&location=%f,%f&rankby=distance&types=accounting|amusement_park|aquarium|art_gallery|atm|bakery|bank|bar|beauty_salon|bicycle_store|book_store|bowling_alley|bus_station|cafe ... university|veterinary_care|zoo"

But by February 16, 2017, the types parameter will be deprecated and replaced with a single type parameter, so I will no longer be able to retrieve every possible nearby location.

What options do I have to be able to still do this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: you are still thinking of Febuary 2017. I guess you have plenty of time to develop your app.You can upgrade it later

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the `types` parameter.  You want the API to restrict to all types, which is the same as wanting no type restriction at all.  You're using `rankby=distance`, so you don't need to set more parameters than the `location`.

Comment: According to Google Places API: "If rankby=distance (described under Optional parameters below) is specified, then one or more of keyword, name, or type is required." If I try the search query as "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=myKeyHere&location=%f,%f&rankby=distance" then no results appear.